# Value of type AppDelegate has no member managedObjectContext in swift 4

Tags: swift, core-data, swift4

I have the code:

```
let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

But xcode reports the error:

> Value of type AppDelegate has no member managedObjectContext.

I would like to find a solution, thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure the error is on that line? Your code does not seem to make an attempt to a `managedObjectContext` property. If you're positive the error is on that line, try cleaning your project, restarting Xcode and then building again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please use below code

```
import CoreData frame work
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext

    return true
}
```

Comment: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not a good example. In the `AppDelegate` class `appDel` is equal to `self`